# Select into #temp table got an error

Tags: sql

I have complicated store procedure and get the data into the #temp table that is worked fine. However when I filter the data from this temp table then I got the error, 'Invalid object name '#temp_2'.  After the data in #temp_2 table, I also need to open into cursor. Would someone tell me how to solve it.

There is my script:

```
DECLARE @sql varchar(500)
IF @strLocations=''
SET @sql='SELECT *  into #temp_2 from #temp_1' 
ELSE
SET @sql='SELECT * into #temp_2 from #temp_1 t  where t.Location_id  in ( ' + @strLocations + ')'
 EXEC (@sql)

select * from #temp_2
```

Comment: I don't see any create table statements.

Comment: the INTO #temp_2 goes before the FROM statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`EXEC` creates a new session to execute the statements. When the session ends, any local temporary tables created in it are destroyed (i.e. dropped). You will have to create the temporary table before your `EXEC` statement.

Comment: Thanks. I created the table to keep the data then delete it.